# Implementing rounded corners on slide down navigation menu

Tags: css, navigation, rounded-corners, slidetoggle

I am working on the slide down menu you can see [here](http://monthlymixup.com/mixups/june_2012/test.html).  I have rounded corners on both `ul#navigation` and `ul.subnavigation`.  When the submenu slides down it is possible to see the border at the bottom of `ul.subnavigation` overlap with the content of `ul#navigation`, when I would like it to slide down smoothly, without the 'flicker'.  I am aware that this issue is caused by the rounded corners.  I need `ul.subnavigation` to cover the rounded corners at the bottom of `ul#navigation` when the menu drops down, without seeing the double border-bottom issue.  I hope this is clear!  Code is below.

Thanks,

Nick

**HTML**

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">menu</a>
        <ul class="sub_navigation">
            <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">help</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">disable tips</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.sub_navigation').slideToggle();
});​
```

**CSS**

```
ul#navigation, ul.sub_navigation {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    min-width:100px;
    background-color: white;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS;
    text-align: center;
    -khtml-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;    
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-top:none;
}

ul.sub_navigation {
    margin-left:-1px;
    position: absolute;
    top:28px;
}

ul#navigation {
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}

ul#navigation li {
    float:left;
    min-width:100px;
}

ul.sub_navigation {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}

ul.sub_navigation li {
    clear:both;
}

 a,
 a:active,
 a:visited {
    display:block;
    padding:7px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why position the submenu? Remove the positioning on it and just hide it till hover triggers.

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qsWa/).